# Como criar uma annotation para validar dados de uma DTO em Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotation

Eu tenho uma classe de um objeto DTO que recebo em meu controle através de uma requisição usando REST. Veja um exemplo de uma requisição usado o verbo Post:

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ExibeDisciplinaDto> insere(@RequestBody InsereDisciplinaDto model) {
    validator.isNaoPodeInserir(model);
    var disciplinaInserida = service.insere(model);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(disciplinaInserida, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Atualmente, o meu validator é um @Component, que tem o nome de DisciplinaValidation. E dentro do método, chamo o método isNaoPodeInserir(model) passando como parâmtro o meu modelo DTO, a cunho de verificar a integridade dos meus dados que estou recebendo na requisição.

Em NestJS eu consegui fazer um recurso fácil usando a linguagem Typescript, e gostaria de saber, se aqui no Java (sou novo) consigo executar essa tarefa, que possa realizar a validação através de uma @annotation? Veja um exemplo de como eu imagino:

```java
@PostMapping
@DataValidation(DisciplinaValidation.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExibeDisciplinaDto> insere(@RequestBody InsereDisciplinaDto 
    var disciplinaInserida = service.insere(model);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(disciplinaInserida, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de validação você precisa/quer fazer no seu DTO?

Comment: Então, mano! Como exemplo, o DTO possui campos de um formulário, e lá dentro dessa classe de validação, faço validações como: tamanho de um texto, se um objeto ou texto esta nulo, verifico a restrições de existência de uma certa entidade no banco, dentre outras coisas. Geralmente, retorno um booleano ou trabalho na emissão de exceptions...

Comment: Acho que isso [aqui](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator-java-bean-validation/) pode lhe ajudar

Comment: Eu sou extremamente grato pela sua colaboração. Eu também cheguei a ver essa documentação antes. É maneiro! Mas, é quase isso, ainda não é a solução deste problema. Essas validações poderiam sim estar dentro da minha classe DTO. Mas, eu chamaria essa classe na assinatura do meu método que recebe requests externos. Por Exemplo: `@DataValidation(DisciplinaValidation.class)`. Dentro de DisciplinaValidation, eu poderia ter as validações do Bean Validation. Mas a Annotation DataValidation é quem iria chamar estas validações.

Comment: Porque você não cria uma "Service" com as suas validações? Se precisar reutilizá-la, pode criar uma "ValidacoesUtils" e chamá-la.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa Atualmente eu tenho isso, mas, posteriormente, eu fiz um esquema no C# em que eu crio esse service e passo em uma anotation. Por Exemplo: @Validator(ServValidator.class), e isso ele os parâmetros que estão sendo passados no método.